# SQL Server Auto-increment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using 3-4 tables and using autoincrement on the primaryk ey in all of them. I want all of the tables to start with 1

For example `student` table id starts from 1, and `Registration` table starts from 1.

Right now what happens auto increments start with the last id of student table. For e.g LastRow ID in student table is 100 so `Registeration` will start from 101. I want it to start from 1 how to do that.

Comment: Have you tried something? Why are you trying to do this? I guess all the tables are empty, because if there is already some value, first one inserted already has the primary key with value 1, so you can't repeat that value.

Comment: is student table empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Einav said this subject is to be handled with caution!

If your student table is empty and you are trying to reset the counters because of testing, or because of a yearly wipe down of the database etc. then you can use the [DBCC CHECKIDENT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) command(if you are using MS SQL Server ) or you can use alter table(auto_increment) for MySql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html.

But be careful as any foreign key dependencies will also have to be reset - you can run into all sorts of trouble.

Here is a quick test scenario:

```
--Test variables & environment
DECLARE @TimeParam AS DATETIME
CREATE TABLE #Downtime (ID int identity, initial varchar(1))
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('a')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('b')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('c')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('d')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('e')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('f')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('g')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('h')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('i')
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('j')

--Queries
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#Downtime)
SELECT ID, initial FROM #Downtime
DELETE FROM #Downtime
DBCC CHECKIDENT (#Downtime, RESEED, 0)
INSERT INTO #Downtime VALUES('k')
SELECT ID, initial FROM #Downtime
DROP TABLE #Downtime

--results (first select)
ID  initial
1   a
2   b
3   c
4   d
5   e
6   f
7   g
8   h
9   i
10  j

--results (second select)
ID  initial
2   j
```

For your case you would use:
    DBCC CHECKIDENT ('Student', RESEED, 0);

Once again handle this command with caution and check all references to this primary key BEFORE running the command.  Make sure you have taken backups of the database too!

Comment: Reseeding to 1, first insert will add identity value 2, not 1.

Comment: Thanks @Yaroslav, I must have been working on autopilot...copy and paste error - answer altered.

Answer (score 3):

If you have some values already (tables not empty) then this is not possible. You could empty all your tables and run [DBCC CHECKIDENT command](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx) to reset the value of your autoincrement primary key and restart from 1.

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ("YourTableNameHere", RESEED, number);
```

If `number` = 0 then in the next insert the auto increment field will contain value 1

If `number` = 101 then in the next insert the auto increment field will contain value 102

But be aware that this command just resets the value of identity column, **it does not check for conflicts**. I mean, if the value 1 already exists then you will have errors when trying to insert on that table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is possible in most RDBMS.
Even if It is, I wouldn't advise you to do it - if there are already rows in the table you should start with MAX_ROWS + 1.

Answer (score 1):

to start the seed from 1 use:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (students, RESEED, 0)
```

note: 
you have to be sure that the table is empty if you are doing this